# active record query depending on count of associated objects

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two models Company and Role related by has_many and belongs_to association respectively. I need to fetch a company that has exactly 'n' number of roles.

I came up with

```
Company.joins(:roles).having("'count(roles.id) = ?', 3")
```

but this does not work. Is there an active record solution to this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Associations -

role belongs_to :company

company has_many :roles

So, selection for criteria would be -

```
Company.joins(:roles).group(:company_id).having('count(company_id)= ?', 3)
```

OR

```
Company.joins(:roles).group(:company_id).having('count(*)= ?', 3)
```

Comment: Looks like i completely mistaken the associations. Can you put associations inside ur company & role models.

Comment: The associations are a company has many roles and a role belongs to a company. I hope this will suffice.

Comment: Look for revised answer based on mentioned associations

Comment: Thanks. Performs exactly what I intended to do. 
The solution suggested by @bricker is indeed worth appreciation but I'll have to mark this as the correct answer as this exactly answers the question.

Comment: Either of those not worked for Rails 5 + postgres 9.5, instead we need change ``group(:company_id)`` to ``group(:company_id, :id)``

Answer (score 6):

I know this is not the answer you're looking for, but the best (in terms of performance) solution is to add a simple `roles_count` column to the `companies` table, and then add `:counter_cache => true` onto the belongs_to association declaration. Rails takes care of updating that column for you.

Then,

```
Company.where("roles_count = ?", 3)
```

More information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-counter_cache

Comment: +1 Yea, that's a good solution in terms of performance. Had nearly forgotten that. Thanks.

Comment: i think counter-cache is performance effective when we expect too many associated records otherwise it could be overburden. what say ??

Comment: @SandipRansing Possibly, but it never hurts to consider scalability when building an application.

Comment: `counter_cache` is exactly what I need! Thanks :)  We have a search page that has an already-complicated query and now we want to add a filter for the count of a particular associated record.  GROUP BY and such would be a disaster, if even possible (and certainly not performant).  `counter_cache` solves it out of the box :D

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, you can use something like `select company_fk from roles GROUP BY company_fk HAVING COUNT(company_fk) = 3;`.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if this will work with mysql, but you could try something like:

```
Company.joins( <<-SQL_SCRIPT, 3 )
  INNER JOIN ( 
               SELECT    "company_id", COUNT("*")
               FROM      "company_roles"
               GROUP BY  "company_id"
             )
          AS  "filter"
          ON  "filter"."company_id" = "companies"."id"
          AND "filter"."count" = ?
SQL_SCRIPT
```

.
where `company_roles` would be the joining table for the HABTM association.

Comment: Thanks. But i'd like to refrain form using complex queries as much as possible.